# Why the value of $1 changed in `{$total=$total+$1}`?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I wrote an `awk` command try to count the total value of a particular column, but something unexpected happened:

```
# THE CONTENT OF TEST FILE
1
2
3
4

# MY AWK COMMAND
awk 'BEGIN {total=0} {print $1; $total=$total+$1; print $1, $total} END {print $total}' test

# RESULT
1
2 2
2
4 4
3
6 6
4
8 8
8
```

Apparently, the value of `$1` changed after `$total=$total+$1`.
But I think I didn't reassign value for `$1`, why it changed unexpectedly, how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `awk` you have to reference a vaiable without the `$` sign, only `total`, not `$total`.

In that `awk` statement:

```
$total=$total+$1
```

`awk` expanded this to (notice the variable `total` is set to `0` in the `BEGIN{}` block):

```
$0=$0+$1
```

So you changed the `$0` value to the value of itself plus the value first field (which is the same), therefore `$0` is set to the double of the value of `$0`. By setting `$0` you also changed the value of `$1`.

---

What you want to achieve, is to sum all values of the first field together. This can be achieved this way:

```
awk '{a+=$1;print a}' file
```

To the value of the `a` variable the value of `$1` is added in each line.

Comment: I got it. Where $total = $ + `value of total`  = $0. And through your last example, awk seems can assign variable in the fly, interesting. My finally command is `awk '{a+=$1} END {print a}' test`

Comment: @Zen Exactly, when you only want to print the sum at the end.